# I am using a singleton class for web services and I want to call cellforrowindexpath in UITableView after JSON data arrived

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I am using singletone class for fetch json data and i want to show in tableview but when i am click view first time then data not showing, on second time it's shows and cell repeating data on every click.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   singCls = [SingletoneClass sharedInstanceMethod];   // Declared Class for instance method of singletone class
   webserviceclas = [[WebserviceUtility alloc] init];
   [webserviceclas getorchardslist];
}
#pragma mark - TableView Delegates
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return singCls.orcharsList.count;   // Get json data of orchards list in array
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *orchardscell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if(orchardscell == nil)
  {

    orchardscell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }
  orchardscell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
  NSString *strcell = [singCls.orcharsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  orchardscell.textLabel.text = strcell;

  // Display Orchards list pass from json
  return orchardscell;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to press `TAB` a couple of times. (Read: format your code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tableview controller was not notified when actual data was fetched by `WebserviceUtility` class. I'm assuming that your `WebserviceUtility` class calls webservices and once the data is received in this class, the singleton class' `orcharsList` array will be updated. So if I'm correct till this point, then you need to notify the tableviewcontroller after updating `orcharsList`. And on receiving notification here, the tableView need to be reloaded and then your tableview delegates will be called.

What you need to do is:

Add protocol method in your `WebserviceUtility` class.

```
@protocol WebServiceDelegate

-(void)fetchedData:(WebserviceUtility*) self;

@end
```

Add a delegate property to which notifications need to be send

```
@interface WebserviceUtility {
    id<WebServiceDelegate>delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <WebServiceDelegate> delegate;
```

Then notify the delegate once data is available

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(fetchedData:)]) {
           [delegate fetchedData:self];
        }
```

Implement those protocols in your tableviewcontroller class and add this class as delegate to WebserviceUtility

In .h file

```
@interface YourTableViewController: UITableViewController<WebServiceDelegate>
```

In .m file, assign your tableviewcontroller as delegate for `WebserviceUtility`

```
webserviceclas = [[WebserviceUtility alloc] init];
webserviceclas.delegate = self;
```

Implement the protocol method in your controller

```
-(void)fetchedData:(WebserviceUtility*) self{
      //Reload your tableview here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you did not embed a callback that notifies your `UITableViewController` to reload data when your singleton finished loading data. Right now there is no data available when first presenting the tableView and it does not refresh automatically.